# Track another URL ruby on rails 3 routes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, custom-routes

I'm trying to mapping my application to a different URL, the default is "/", i'm trying to send all pages to "/application_home" how can i do this configuring the routes file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is slightly unclear. Are you trying to move the entire rails application on your server or are you trying to reroute requests within the app itself?

You can find lots of great info about rails routes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#customizing-resourceful-routes) in the rails guides.

```
root :to => "your_controller#your_action", :as => "your_curstom_name"
```